# cakephp 3 : static pages whith inflected route

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can a create static pages in the admin part (inflected route) of the application ?

/pages/info works fine

but /admin/pages/info do not works

I've added the PagesController.php to Controller/Admin

Create the Template/Admin/Pages/info.ctp file

Add the route :

```
$routes->connect('/admin/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display','admin'=>true]);
```

and get this error :

```
Error: The view for PagesController::display() was not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Controller\AppController;
```

was missing